# How to permanently enable Sublime Text 3 LiveReload plugin

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, livereload

I recently installed the LiveReload [plugin](https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2) for Sublime Text 3. I also installed the LiveReload Chrome extension. Everything works great, however there's one remaining headache. I need to go into package control in Sublime and enable the LiveReload Simple Reload plugin every time I open Sublime. 
Is there a way to permanently enable Sublime Text 3 LiveReload plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed: https://github.com/Grafikart/ST3-LiveReload

Next: preferences -> Packge Settings -> LiveReload -> Settings - User

Add:

```
{ 
    "enabled_plugins": [
        "SimpleRefresh"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

{
    "enabled_plugins": [
    "SimpleReloadPlugin", "SimpleRefresh" 
]
}